# SQL Server : how do I get SQL to recognize ö and ß correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, globalization

I currently have a table that has 4 columns. The `ID` of the object, `ID` of another object in another table, `nvarchar` data, and a `bool`.

PK is made up of the first 3 columns.

The values `größe` conflicts with `grösse`, and `große` conflicts with `grosse`

meaning I can have one of the first two and one of the second two, but not all of them

The column has collation set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CS_AS`

I believe this is where the problem lies but this does handle many other unicode characters correctly. Has anyone encountered this and know what my problem is?

For reference both of these play okay with all of the above.

```
gråsse
grøsse
```

Example for clarity, for me this is printing equal:

```
IF (N'grösse' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = N'größe' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'EQUAL' 
END
```

When I expect these to be different.

Comment: QL_Latin1_General_CS_AS doesn't handle any unicode characters.  It does handle a few LATIN characters like A with accent mark, or E with accent mark. (Accent doesn't automatically mean unicode.) Just change the table to UFT8.

Comment: @developerwjk SQL Server does not have UTF-8. Maybe you are talking about MySQL?!

Comment: You can always store the column as binary and deal with it in the client. But I'm sure you know that in one sense, grösse and große are identical?

Comment: @ErikE - No need to store as binary. Can just use a binary collation if it has the desired semantics.

Comment: FWIW this can be reproduced by the following snippet: `SELECT CASE WHEN 'ss' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'ß' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS result`

Comment: @usr, Yes it does, unless you're running a version that's ridiculously old maybe. If the up to date versions of Microsoft SQL didn't support UTF8, Microsoft would go out of business.

Comment: @developerwjk - It doesn't have a simple mechanism to "Just change the table to UFT8". 2012 introduced `SC` ("supplementary character") collations that support the whole of UTF-16 though.

Comment: @Martin Smith, So maybe Microsoft will go out of business after all and we'll be saved from Windows 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> handle many other unicode characters **correctly**

What does correctly mean to you? The different collations in SQL Server have different behavior. Maybe you are looking for a binary collation like `LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN2`. This one compares code-points only. Duplicates will only occur when the strings are binary-identical. Your example code would behave like you want it to.

The non-binary collations try to apply lexicographic rules. They sort and compare strings like a phone book would.

Comment: This does perform correctly in the example.  I will need to learn more about the differences between these collations before implementing a solution but it looks likely this is my issue.

For my question "correctly" means viewing all those string examples as different.